# Failed to refresh the collection list. Please try again later

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

For the past few months I've had an intermittent issue with connecting to CosmosDB through the Azure Portal when trying to use the Data Explorer. I get the error: "Failed to refresh the collection list. Please try again later."

I added my IP Address, enabled "Allow access from Azure Portal" and "Accept connections from within public Azure datacenters" but I am still unable to access or browse my data.

I've tried to disable/renable the firewall rules but this made no difference. I can't contact Microsoft as I have a developer account and they charge for support, so before I go down that route I wanted to see if anyone else had the issue?

[image: Error: "Failed to refresh the collection list. Please try again later."]

Comment: This is related to product usage issue, program issue instead. So it's off-topic here. I think it's better to contact azure team to ask official support directly,which is more effective.

Comment: I believe this is related to your subscription account being disabled by azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by Azure support. If the subscription disabled due to a spending cap and is enabled again at the start of the month, this doesn't flow through to CosmosDB and has to be 'unblocked' by Azure support.

Seemed so unlikely that this would be the cause of issue, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can happen to cause this.

I wrote a console app that allowed /b (backspace) into the database name. This created a URI filled with /b/b/b and also /0/0/0 (nulls) for some reason.
documents.azure.com/dbs/SuperDuper%08%08%08%08%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00... you get the point.

Nothing unusual about the call..
`await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(id: DBName, throughputProperties: SetRU);`

This resulted in this

[image]

No current resolution but in my case its just a dev space so I can just recreate it.